# 2G Network throttling in Chrome

Tags: browser, google-chrome-devtools, playwright, throttling

does anyone know what should be values to simulate 2G in ChromeDevTools? Similar to this slow 3G

```
export const Slow3GConditions: Conditions = {
  title: i18nLazyString(UIStrings.slowG),
  i18nTitleKey: UIStrings.slowG,
  download: 500 * 1000 / 8 * .8,
  upload: 500 * 1000 / 8 * .8,
  latency: 400 * 5,
};
```

Those are values from Firefox:

450kbps, 150kbps, 150ms Good2G

750kbps, 250kbps, 100ms Regular3G

According to https://www.debugbear.com/blog/chrome-devtools-network-throttling, CDP is implemented differently so it has different values, but I suppose ratio should stay the same?

Thanks in advance!

exact numbers for 2G throttling in Chrome